# Finding $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z^{6}+z^{3}+2|= 4+|4z^{2}+4|$

Tags: complex-numbers

everyone. I don't know how to start to solve this exercise that asks for the $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $$|z^6+z^3+2|= 4 +|4z^2+4|$$
And
$$|z|=1$$

I tried finding the roots of $z^6+z^3+2$ but that didn't help me to find the region that describes $|z^6+z^3+2|= 4 +|4z^2+4|$.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:$\;\,$Since $|z|=1$, the LHS can't be greater than $4$.

Comment: Why ${}{}{}$...?

Comment: The absolute value of a sum is less than or equal to . . .

Comment: @MyGlasses triangle inequality

Comment: Can someone tell me what you are trying to solve with |z| = 1?

Comment: @qbert Really in the best case $4z^2+4$ at the RHS will be $0$ or $z=\pm i$ which give $\sqrt{2}=4$.

Comment: +1: Very slick!